# XCode Ambiguous reference to member

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Recently I upgraded my XCode to version 8.  After doing so I was unable to compile my project because I got a Swift Compiler Error.  Here is an example of what the errors are:
Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'
Ambiguous use of 'appendingPathComponent'
Ambiguous reference to member 'continue'
etc,

What could be causing this bugs after updating and how can I resolve them?

Answer (score 1):

Ambiguous reference to member 'continue'.
In XCode 8 the syntax is going to be:

```
credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continue( {(task:AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
```

instead of

```
credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continue { (task:AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
```